# getting odd or even value from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> in android

Tags: java, android

I have a hashmap variable like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  myfullvalue;
```

this map filled with all my values from tables.
there is a field in this map with unique number.
now i just want to get even and odd values from "myfullvalues"
base on "Id"  and make two other  one like :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  myevenvalue;
```

and

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  myoddvalue;
```

for single value i used this :

```
if (Integer.parseInt((myevenvalue.get(0).get("id"))) & 1 == 0)  { even... } else { odd... }
```

but dont know how to do it with assigning it to new array one.

Comment: First thing which catch the eye: you apply bitwise operator to String `myevenvalue.get(0).get("id")) & 1 == 0`.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean by _"dont know how to do it with assigning it to new array one"_?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare, the problem is i want to Filter "myfullvalue" array and get only values with odd "id" and put it in new array.
same happen to even "id" too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `%` operator to  find even/odd

try this code

```
for(HashMap<String, String> : myevenvalue){

if (Integer.parseInt((myevenvalue.get(0).get("id"))) % 2 == 0)  
 { even... } 
else { odd... }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , how can i do that for all value in the array ? like filter out all even one and assign it to new array ?

Comment: Thanks alot that do the tricks but couldnt accept more than one answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete answer:

**Step 1)** Remember to initialize the arraylists.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  myevenvalue = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  myoddvalue =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

**Step 2)** Loop through the `myfullvalue` list and add items based on even or odd.

```
for(HashMap<String, String> map : myfullvalue) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(map.get("id"));
    if(id % 2 == 0) {
        myevenvalue.add(map);
    } else {
        myoddvalue.add(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:--

```
for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : myfullvalue) {

        if (Integer.parseInt(hashMap.get("id")) % 2 == 0) {
            myevenvalue.add(new HashMap(hashMap));
        } else {
            myoddvalue.add(new HashMap(hashMap));
        }
    }
```